# OK to use two "there"s in a sentence?

Tags: sentence, phrasing, there-is

A teacher once told me that it is improper to use two *there* words in a sentence, such as

> There is a woman there.

or

> Is there a man there?

and instead state

> A woman is there.

or

> Is a man there?

even though it's completely fine to state

> There is a woman here.

or

> Is there a man here?

Is there correct advice there? :-)

Comment: There, there, now... that's odd that you asked that.  Two theres?  Seems like we do do that sometimes.  I guess your teacher never read [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=nAYGcftgT20C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22there+is+a+car+there%22&source=bl&ots=mV_abRLm4h&sig=OxO4ZphM4xrQf1aB02D8bApQ1S8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yoVlUI-QKenbyAHK_YCABQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22there%20is%20a%20car%20there%22&f=false).  Too often teachers tell us to "avoid" things, or "never do" things, when they really mean "be careful about" doing things.  There's a lesson there, I think.

Comment: It's not improper grammatically because each *there* is fulfilling a different purpose. It might be bad **style**.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I don't see that each fulfilling a different purpose  really has a bearing on grammaticality. By that rationale, either J.R.'s *"There, there, now..."* is ungrammatical, or *they're* fulfilling different purposese.

Comment: There is no there there.

Comment: @F Each fulfilling a different purpose makes it grammatical. That JR's aren't does not make his sentence ungrammatical. I can't draw a Venn diagram in a comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "improper" in any sense.

In speech it's unexceptionable, because the intonation is so very different that there's no possibility of confusion.

But your teacher's point, that it's generally a good idea to avoid using the same (graphic) word in different senses, is  correct. Here's what Graves & Hodge (*The Reader Over Your Shoulder*) say about it:

> ***The same word should not be used in different senses in the same passage, unless attention is called to the difference***
>
> If one searches in the kitchen-cupboard for a missing egg-cup and does not find it, though it is there, the chances are that it is doing duty as a mustard-pot—the eye refuses to recognize it as an egg-cup. Similarly, if the same word is used in different senses in a passage, the reader's eye will often fail to recognize the second word—it cannot grasp, as it were, that an egg-cup can also be a mustard-pot.

Among their examples is this:

> From a newspaper report:
> "The mob of frightened little children reached the fire-alarm, but were unable to reach it."

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about avoiding the same word in different senses. Isn't that the whole idea of syllepsis to implicitly (without actually repeating it) use the same word in different senses?

Comment: @Gnubie  Yes, if you're doing it on purpose, for rhetorical or humorous purposes, it's fine--that's G&H's "unless attention is called to the difference".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your teacher.  While not technically prohibited, it makes for clumsy sentences.